# React bad performance in list while selecting a listitem

Tags: reactjs, list, performance, optimization, react-hooks

So I am currently in my final stages of finishing a webapp in React.
In this stage I am looking for performance issues and I am trying to optimize the performance.

So I have 3 components:

RulePage, RuleList (Contains a list of OrderRules), OrderRule

When I select (highlight) an OrderRule, it gets different CSS and the **id** of the OrderRule is being sent to the page through the list, because the page must send requests for a selected orderRule, so it needs the ID.

However, when I select an orderRule, every item in the OrderRuleList rerenders and that causes some bad performance on mobile devices.

I tried some things with useMemo, but unfortunately I was not able to fix the performance issue.

Here's my code, simplified:

Page:

```
const [rules, setRules] = useState([]);
const [selected, setSelected] = useState(null);

function setSelectedRule(oid){ setSelected(oid); }

return (
    {rules && <OrderRuleList selected={selected} setSelectedRule={setSelectedRule} rules={rules} {...aLotOfProps}/>}
);
```

List:

```
function setSelectedRule(oid){
    props.setSelectedRule(oid);
}

return (
    {props.rules.map((rule) => <OrderRule selected={props.selected} data={rule} setSelectedRule={setSelectedRule} {...moreProps}/>)}
);
```

ListItem:

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState(props.selected === props.data?.Oid);
const rule = props.data;

return (
    <div onClick={() => props.setSelectedRule(rule?.Oid)}>
        {...otherStuff}
    </div>
);
```

Does anyone have any tips for optimization? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to optimise the performance is to remove the local state from `OrderRule` component.

Heres an example:

**Page**:

```
const [rules, setRules] = useState([]);
const [selected, setSelected] = useState(null);

function setSelectedRule(oid) { 
    setSelected(oid); 
}

return (
    {rules && <OrderRuleList selected={selected} setSelectedRule={setSelectedRule} rules={rules} {...aLotOfProps}/>}
);
```

**List**:

```
function setSelectedRule(oid) {
    props.setSelectedRule(oid);
}

return (
    {props.rules.map((rule) => <OrderRule selected={props.selected === rule.Oid} data={rule} setSelectedRule={setSelectedRule} {...moreProps}/>)}
);
```

**ListItem**:

```
const rule = props.data;

return (
    <div onClick={() => props.setSelectedRule(rule?.Oid)} className={props.selected ? 'selected' : ''}>
        {...otherStuff}
    </div>
);
```

The `OrderRuleList` checks if the current rule is selected one while mapping over the rules. The value is passed down to the `OrderRule` component.

`OrderRule` no longer has local state. Instead, the `'selected'` prop that it receives from OrderRuleList is directly used to determine if it should have the 'selected' class.

Lastly, i would suggest implementing `React.memo` to prevent unnecessary renders. If you have a lot of complex props, consider using `useMemo` or `useCallback` hooks for those props.

**EDIT: Example of how to use `memo`**

Please note that i dont have access to your full code base so this example is from what i think it should be.

**Page**:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import OrderRuleList from './OrderRuleList';

export default function RulePage(props) {
    const [rules, setRules] = useState([]);
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState(null);

    function setSelectedRule(oid) { 
        setSelected(oid); 
    }

    return (
        {rules && <OrderRuleList selected={selected} setSelectedRule={setSelectedRule} rules={rules} {...props}/>}
    );
}
```

**List**:

```
import React from 'react';
import OrderRule from './OrderRule';

export default function OrderRuleList(props) {
    const setSelectedRule = (oid) => {
        props.setSelectedRule(oid);
    }

    return (
        {props.rules.map((rule) => <OrderRule key={rule.Oid} selected={props.selected === rule.Oid} data={rule} setSelectedRule={setSelectedRule} {...props}/>)}
    );
}
```

**ListItem**:

```
import React from 'react';

function OrderRule(props) {
    const rule = props.data;

    return (
        <div onClick={() => props.setSelectedRule(rule?.Oid)} className={props.selected ? 'selected' : ''}>
            {...props.otherStuff}
        </div>
    );
}

export default React.memo(OrderRule);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, especially the remark of the double states.
Can you give me an example of where i can use memo here?

Comment: @Takkie253 please take a look at the update.

Comment: Thank you for the example! See the other answer for how I got it fixed with your suggestions.

Comment: Great work @Takkie253

Answer (score 0):

Memoing like @jagmitg did, didn't solve the case, but I found a solution based on his suggestions that did work:

```
const MemoRule = React.memo(OrderRule, (prevProps, nextProps) => 
{
    return !(prevProps.selected === prevProps.rule?.Oid || nextProps.selected === nextProps.rule?.Oid);
});
    
export default MemoRule;
```

This causes a check: when an orderrule was selected before and not anymore, it gets rerenderd OR when an orderrule is being selected and was not selected before, it gets rerenderd.